# 500 ERROR! Magento 2.1.3 Enable Multistore after fresh migration from 1.8

Tags: magento-2.1, magento-2.0, magento-2.1.3

Can someone shed some light on Magento 2.1.3 enabling multistore?

things I have tried;

enabling index.php
code is dev
website url is dev.example.com

```
<?php
$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'dev.dev.example.com';
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
?>
```

enabling .htaccess with index.php
code is dev
website url is dev.example.com

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)dev\.example\.com
RewriteRule .* – [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:dev.dev.example_com]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)dev\.example\.com
RewriteRule .* – [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website
```

enabling vhost.conf with index.php
code is dev
website url is dev.example.com

```
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "dev.dev.example.com"
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "website"
```

enabling index.php and old .htaccess

```
SetEnvIf Host dev\.example\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=dev_example_com
SetEnvIf Host dev\.example\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^example\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=dev_example_com
SetEnvIf Host ^example\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

have tried enabling vhost with .htaccess and index.php
and vhost with .htaccess the old .htaccess and index.php

all of which have produced a Magento 500 error or the servers internal server error page

Also, have tried uncommenting this section of the index.php page. Although didn't give me any errors it isn't working correctly either. For example, I have removed a category from displaying in the header for this site and it still shows up like in default site. Also tried with .htaccess and as well.

```
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
 $params = $_SERVER;
 $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'example.com';
 $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'dev.example.com';
 $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
```

Comment: Did you add those coding to your non-default store index.php file?

Comment: Added it to things I have tried :)

Comment: Can you please provide the actual error message?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to a bug in 2.1.3 that prevented website scope configurations from working - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7943

I'd suggest that you upgrade your installation to 2.1.7 and see if the issue still occurs.